# Unsure which possessive form to use

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe

If I say

> The first *groups presentation was on insects.

is it **group's** or **groups'**?

Comment: If you can say "The presentation of the first group" instead, then it is possessive, with an apostrophe. Possessives always take an apostrophe on nouns; it's only pronouns that cause trouble.

Comment: Also see: [ell.se]

Comment: Do you mean "a presentation by a particular group"? Or do you mean "a series of presentations called *groups*"?

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one *The first group*, so singular. *The first **group's*** -- singular with an apostrophe-s.

The one exception would be where you intend to say the first (few) groups. However, there would then be ambiguity. One would better avoid *first* with a plural as in that case.

> The first **group's** presentation was on insects.

As Prof. Lawler observed, it is better to use the *of* form in formal writing instead of the apostrophe in such cases.

> The presentation of the first **group** was on insects.